# libcurl, OSX, curl_multi_perform bad access

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, exc-bad-access, libcurl

I recently wrote a C++ library that uses libcurl for http requests. A colleague of mine began using it on OSX for an application written in Objective-C. For the most part it works just fine. But for some reason, on a multipart post call, we are seeing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a curl_multi_perform call.

Right now I am stuck, I originally developed this on my Linux machine, and have since written programs that use the library with no problems. Being rather new to the *nix development ecosystem and having little to no experience developing on OSX I'm not quite sure how to approach debugging this.

I did insert a post function that was line for line this example, just to get a base line, to see if the problem persisted, it did.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html

To recap, the lib itself is written in C++ calling libcurl methods. It work fine on several linux machines i've tested it on. On OSX, in an Objective C Project, when calling the multipart post function, bad access error.

Where do I go from here? How can I further narrow this problem down? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run your program in valgrind on your Linux box? It may find something wrong which is not fatal on your system but is on another.

Comment: Yes I just tried this, I got "Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)" and "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" around the libcurl calls, but from what I've read these are probably not issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more familiar with OSX and Xcode. Xcode provides very extensive memory error debugging methods. Libcurl could be the cause of error. I recommend to obtain your own debug build of libcurl.

Please refer to this document: [Mac OS X Debugging Magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html)